# How to pass signal through application to connected device using dock connector in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am working on an application that will get signal when device connect through iPhone dock connector and can send signals also to the attached device.

Please guide me from very initial stage.. Thanks.

Comment: Apple provides information about the External Accessory framework at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not worked with it directly myself, but you need to read up on the [External Accessory Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008235). There is also some [Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502) discussed.

Googling gives you some other references that may be useful. E.g http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/09/14/communicating-with-external-devices-from-the-iphone-and-ipad/

Comment: I have already gone through External Accessory Framework and make a dummy aap but it does not show attached device details. Can you please send me any working example?